# How to plot ARIMA prediction/forecast with statsmodels 0.14.0

Tags: python, plot, statsmodels, arima

In older versions of the python package statsmodels, there was a `plot_predict` method in the ARIMAResults class. With the new version, there are only `forecast`, `get_forecast`, `predict` and `get_prediction` methods, but as far as I could see, no built-in plotting method for the results.

Is there a way to get a similar plot to the one the old `plot_predict` method generated?

Answer (score 1):

This code works with statsmodels 0.14.0:

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_predict

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

ax.plot(pd.DataFrame(train).loc[354:].reset_index(drop=True), '-g', label='observed')

plot_predict(model_fit, start=354, end=365, ax=ax);
```

Hint: look up source code and search for plot_predict:

[source code for statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/graphics/tsaplots.html)